# How to write several images without overlapping

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, split, image-segmentation

I am trying to write contour images but i am getting only one image as output. I had 3 images and i want to write all 3 image contour output.

I want to create a sub folder under the name of filename and write the segmented images to the relevant folders.

I was trying to implement os.path.split but till now no success

```
import sys
import glob,os
import cv2
class Imageprocessing:
    def readImages(inputFolder):
        ext = ['.png', '.jpg', '.gif', '.jpeg', '.tif', '.tiff']    # Add image formats here
        files = []
        path = inputFolder + "\\*.*"
        #print (path)
        files = glob.glob(path)
        #[files.extend(glob.glob(inputFolder + '*.' + e)) for e in ext]
        #print(files)
        imageFiles=[]
        for i in files:
            exten=os.path.splitext(i)[1]
            if exten in ext:
                imageFiles.append(i)
        return imageFiles

    def processImage(imageFiles):
        for imagePath in imageFiles:
            print(imagePath)
            image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
            cv2.imshow("1",image)
            cv2.waitKey()
            ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
            edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 200)
            #cv2.imshow('original_image',image)
            #cv2.imshow('2',thresh)
            #cv2.imshow('3',edges)
            #cv2.waitKey()
            #cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            contours,hierachy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            for contour in contours:
                cv2.drawContours(image, [contour], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            cv2.imwrite(sys.argv[1]+".jpg", image)

imageFiles = Imageprocessing.readImages(sys.argv[1])
Imageprocessing.processImage(imageFiles)
```

1:

[image: 1]

2:

[image: 2]

3:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have asked , the below code will 'Create sub folder under the name of filename and write the segmented images to the relevant folders'.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob,os,sys
class Imageprocessing:  
    def readImages(inputFolder):
        ext = ['.png', '.jpg', '.gif', '.jpeg', '.tif', '.tiff']
        files = []
        path = inputFolder + "/*.*"
        files = glob.glob(path)
        imageFiles=[]
        for i in files:
                exten=os.path.splitext(i)[1]
                if exten in ext:
                        imageFiles.append(i)
        return imageFiles

    def processImage(imageFiles):
        for imagePath in imageFiles:
            img_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(imagePath))[0]
            new_folder = sys.argv[2]+'/'+img_name+'/'
            os.makedirs(new_folder, exist_ok=True)

            image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
            kernel = np.ones((10, 0), np.uint8)
            dilated_img = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=0)
            img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_img.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            sorted_ctrs = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

            for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
                    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
                    cv2.drawContours(image, [ctr], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
                    roi = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                    if w > 3 and h > 10:
                            cv2.imwrite(new_folder+'{}.png'.format(i), roi)

            cv2.imshow('contours', image)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

imageFiles = Imageprocessing.readImages(sys.argv[1])
Imageprocessing.processImage(imageFiles)
# press 'esc' to close the image window
# execute as : python file.py path\to\input path\to\output 
# each argument seperated by space
```

this will create a folder for each filename at location specified as `sys.argv[2]` as segmented images with contours drawn over.

[image]
[image]

you can adjust the 'w' and 'h' in `if w > 3 and h > 10:`, or the kernel, or the value of iterations in 'cv2.dilate', to adjust this code to different sizes of characters inside your image file. (currently the code is tuned to the image link you have provided)

Comment: Thanks for answering well i am able to do that but now i want segment words(crop individual characters from image)and save them as a .jpg file.If you can help me with this i will be highly thankful (for clarity image basically have 4-5 characters which need to be segmented and save as individual files)

Comment: @AnimeshKumarSingh, provide a link for your image

Comment: •Create sub folder under the name of filename and write the segmented images to the relevant folders.Question Updated....

Comment: In above program you are specifying the path to save file same as the input path but i want specify input folder on command prompt and output folder(where i want to save segmented images) also on command prompt in the form of argument.And In recent program contour images are not being saved just the segmented images are being saved.

Comment: for making my question simple here are the things i need to do...          •Read all the images from folder by specifying the location from command Prompt , which accept all image formats other than PDF.
•Find contours and write all contour images in to specified the output folder using command prompt by specifying where to save those.
•Create sub folder under the name of filename and write the segmented images to the relevant folders using command prompt for specifying the location where to save those files.

Comment: of you want to specify your output folder from command prompt, give it as a second argument and get it inside the function using `sys.argv[2]`. (`python file.py path\to\input path\to\output`), each argument separated using space

Comment: @AnimeshKumarSingh updated . will now save segmented images with contours to specified location (location as an argument in command line)